# Unable to retrieve logged in user specific content on html page in django

Tags: django

I have successfully created a login page and i am able to login the user after signing them up. But i fail to retrieve the user data and display it in user's home page apart from user's username and email(which come up with inbuilt User model since i have inherited it.).
Here i want to show the profile picture of the user on its home page after logging in.Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User)
first_Name=models.CharField(max_length=26,default=" ")
last_Name=models.CharField(max_length=26,default=" ")
gender=models.CharField(max_length=10)
father_name=models.CharField(max_length=56)
profile_pic=models.ImageField(max_length=100,upload_to='profile_pics')


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
      profile=Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
      instance.profile.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

forms.py

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

```
class Meta():
    model = User
    fields=('username','password')
```

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta():
    model=Profile
    fields=('first_Name','last_Name','gender','father_name','profile_pic')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def IndexView(request,user_id):
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
profile_pict=user.profile.profile_pic
return render(request,"studenthome.html",{
    'username': user.username,
    'address':user.profile.address,
    'profile_pict':profile_pict,

})



class LoginView(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name="login.html"

def get(self,request):
    form=self.form_class(None)
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

def post(self, request):
    password = request.POST['password']
    username = request.POST['username']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            if user.is_staff:
               login(request, user)
               return render(request,'teacher.html',{'username':user.username})
            else:
               login(request,user)
               return render(request,'studenthome.html',{'username':user.username})
            #    return redirect('IITMApp:index')

        else:
            return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
    else:
        # return redirect("IITApp:login")
        return render(request, 'login.html',{
        'login_message' : 'Enter the username and password correctly',})

    return render(request, "studenthome.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code you are only passing username to your template instead if complete user object. See line:

`return render(request,'teacher.html',{'username':user.username})`

if instead if this you pass it as:

`return render(request,'teacher.html',{'user':user})`

also you can use django's default login function as given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login).

you will be able to access all the fields of user model in your template.

Let me know if this doesn't work.